# How to dynamically fill an input text field in CakePHP using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, jquery-events

I have an "Add Person" form with a few fields (name, address, phone number, etc).

I want to be able to pre-fill some of the fields using information from other fields BEFORE submitting the form. For example, once the user puts in a city, an Ajax query will pull the area-code for the phone number (the Controller has a "city to area code" database) and put it in the phone number field, hoping it will save some typing.

I've tried using `observeField`, but it seems like it can only change the innerHTML of an element, not the value of an input field.

Any suggestions of how to go about?

Comment: What would you do with big metro areas like LA or Houston that have 3+ area codes? I'd suggest a drop down, but then it's not user-editable, and I might have a phone number I got when I lived in New York but now (thanks to cell phone plans) I live in Chicago. I know it's not your question, but just a heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have two forms:

```
<form id="formOriginal">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="address"/>
    <input type="text" name="city"/>
    <input type="text" name="state"/>
</form>

<form id="formCopy">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="address"/>
    <input type="text" name="city"/>
    <input type="text" name="state"/>
</form>
```

You should be able to loop through the items and copy values as follows:

```
$('#formOriginal input').each(function(e) {
    var name = e.attr('name');
    var $copy = $('#formCopy input[@name=' + name + ']');

    if ($copy) {
        $copy.val($(e).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the value on a text input, then you can use [.val()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val)

So in your ajax success you will have a callback:

```
success: function(data){
  $('#foo').val(data);
}
```